# how to solve the download error in AIX?

Tags: aix

im getting the following error in suma logs during the update download,

how to solve this...

---

20110516 04:48:18 V 0500-012 An error occurred attempting to download.

20110516 04:48:18 I Logging operations stopped,

20110516 04:48:20 I Logging operations started,

20110516 04:50:50 E 0500-013 Failed to retrieve list from fix server.

20110516 04:50:51 V 500 (Internal Server Error) Can't connect to www14.software.ibm.com:80 (connect: Invalid argument)

---

Update Error: Failed to download filesets for Maintenance Level 5300-08 by SUMA

Comment: You've got 5 questions related to getting SUMA working on AIX; either this is not a professional environment (where you should have called IBM weeks ago) or you're very lucky to still have a job. It's pretty obvious you don't know what you're doing; why haven't you called a professional yet?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have direct Internet access from the machine?
In a corporate environment I would guess not and you need to set your proxy server.

Comment: yes i have configured proxy... where can i give the proxy in suma.. during manual configuration using smit

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/270114/how-to-solve-the-download-error-in-aix/270126#270126 yes i have configured proxy...